# AdMob + Slow to display content + Google DFP

Tags: ios, admob

I'm having a little trouble implementing AdMob with my iOS app.

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView and an ad on the bottom.

In the viewDidLoad method I request the ad to load.

While the ad loads the UITableView fills the entire view.
When the ad loads, the delegate method adViewDidReceiveAd:(DFPBannerView *)bannerView is called. This is where I adjust the frames of both the ad and UITableView.

This all works great, except for one small issue.

When adViewDidReceiveAd:(DFPBannerView *)bannerView is called, I set the frames but the ad still doesn't display for up to 5 seconds. This is not visually pleasing because for a second or two - there is just a blank space at the bottom of the screen.

It is almost as if adViewDidReceiveAd:(DFPBannerView *)bannerView is called when the ad data has loaded but not the actual 'ad view'. i.e. it's loading the UIWebView of the ad after that method is called.

Is this making any sense to anyone?
Can anyone help?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

**I should mention I am using Google DFP which then connects to AdMob to find ads.**
I have since tested the same code with a publisherID directly from AdMob. This fixes the display problem.

So, I think this narrows the problem down to Google DFP.

Comment: I see that you're using the DFPBannerView, are you sure it's not something with your creative? You can probably test this by trying to request a test ad (use the testDevices method on GADRequest).

Comment: I don't think that's it, because while I'm using DFP - I am only using AdMob ads through DFP...for now. Setting requests to test mode doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I can confirm that disabling googletag DFP results in noticeably faster loading of page content--this despite the fact that we're using their async code to circumvent this issue. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the ad in the `init()` not in the `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there are cases where setting the `frame` of the `GADBannerView` requests another ad so you might be falling into a trap where this is happening (when the frame you set is different from the ad size requested). Can you check if another request is going out when you do this?

Can you try hiding your `GADBannerView` and showing it to see if you see that same lag?